# Solve this equation $(x,y) \cdot (x,y) + (2,0)=(0,0)$ in $\mathbb{Q}^{2}$

Tags: calculus

> Let $\mathbb{Q}^{2}= \mathbb{Q} \times \mathbb{Q}= \left\{(a,b): a,b
> \in \mathbb{Q}\right\}$ be the set of rational numbers and we have two
>   operations $+$ and $\cdot$ for all $(a_{1},b_{1}),(a_{2},b_{2}) \in
> \mathbb{Q}^{2}$ by the following rule
>
> $$(a_{1},b_{1})+(a_{2},b_{2})=(a_{1}+a_{2},b_{1}+b_{2}),$$
>
> $$(a_{1},b_{1}) \cdot
> (a_{2},b_{2})=(a_{1}a_{2}-2b_{1}b_{2},a_{1}b_{2}+a_{2}b_{1}).$$
>
> Solve this equation $(x,y) \cdot (x,y) + (2,0)=(0,0)$ in
>   $\mathbb{Q}^{2}$ and specify all solutions.

I did it like this:

$$(x^{2}-2y^{2},xy+yx)+(2,0)=(0,0)$$

$$(x^{2}-2y^{2}+2,xy+yx+0)=(0,0)$$

But what then? This is very confusing and I doubt I did it correct till here...? : /

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Why do you doubt? It seems like all you did is correct.

Note that the standard multiplication is commutative, so $xy+yx+0=2xy$, so you have $2xy=0$. What can you deduce from that?

Comment: @berndgr Not necessarily both. For instance, $2\cdot 5\cdot 0$ is still $0$.

Comment: Sorry I don't know then.. Either $x$ or $y$ or both will equal $0$? But how to write this all in the correct notation?

Comment: @berndgr: That's correct. What do you mean by "the correct notation"? You've just written it down in a perfectly correct way: "Either $x$ or $y$ or both will equal $0$". Which leaves you with three cases to consider. (Or just two, if you allow them to overlap.)

Comment: So I'm alright if I write as in my question above and then write what you have just written above this comment? Then I'm done? :)

Comment: @berndgr: Not completely. You only solved half of it. You still need to have $x^2-2y^2+2=0$. This only has one solution if one of $x,y$ is zero.

Comment: @berndgr: (Actually, it has two solutions, sorry for misinformation.)

Comment: So $2xy=0$ will have one solution and $x^{2}+2y^{2}+2=0$ will have two solutions. In total all this will have two solutions then, is that right? I really hope so because this thing, got still troubles understanding :(

Comment: It's saying "specify all solutions", any idea how this could be done? What about?: $$\mathbb{L}=\left\{(x,y) \in \mathbb{Q}^{2}| y=\sqrt{\frac{1}{2}x^{2}+1}\text{ and }y=0\right\}$$

Comment: @berndgr: No, if you assume that $2xy=0$, there are two possible pairs $(x,y)$ for which you have $x^2+2y^2+2$. I have no idea what you are talking about in your second comment.

Comment: The task isn't asking for how many solutions there are, it's rather asking for what the solutions are, specific values.. I don't know how to write it, tried above L=..

Comment: @berndgr: Simply solve the equation for $x=0$ and $y=0$ separately...

Comment: $x=0 \Rightarrow -2y^{2}+2=0 \Rightarrow y=+-1$ and if $y=0$ then $x^{2}+2=0$ which isn't solvable. So $$\mathbb{L}=\left\{-1,1\right\}$$? Oh but this wouldn't satisfy the other equation $2xy=0$..

Comment: @berndgr: The solutions are in ${\bf Q}^2$, so they should be $(0,-1)$ and $(0,1)$.